# firefox (Gecko) conditional style sheet

Tags: css, firefox, stylesheet

today I'm trying to optimize my website for a better rendering in firefox!
my problems are the text-shadow and font-weight properties ... I would like to set custom values only for firefox (my website is mac only compatible so I don't need IE compatibility) but I don't wont to use separate style sheet for only these two properties!!!
There is any way to do that? Or I must use a php script to filter the user agent and load customized style sheets for firefox?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem like you would want to support ONLY browsers which support `text-shadow`, so why only target Firefox? Your approach should be to only change `font-weight` for those browsers which support `text-shadow`. But this is easier said than done.

Browser sniffers are not going to work unless they can differentiate between Firefox 3.5 and earlier versions. The one linked to by KahWee would not achieve this, but I would NOT recommend browser sniffing anyway -- it is not best practice.

I would instead recommend setting `font-weight` to whatever is meant for use with `text-shadow`, and then include an IE conditional to reset the *majority* of visitors' browsers back to the original, non-shadowed `font-weight`.

Example:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .some-text {
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: #000 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
    }
</style>

<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .some-text {
         font-weight: normal;
         text-shadow: none; /* Does nothing now, but explicitly define NONE
            for future IE versions as that is what is intended */
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

With this you will achieve `text-shadow` with proper `font-weight` in these browsers:

- Firefox 3.5+
- Opera 9.5+
- Safari 1.1+ (Since 2003!)
- Chrome 2.0+
- Konqueror 3.4+

And if you want drop shadow in IE you can use `filter` expressions with `DropShadow()`, but I personally do not recommend using proprietary CSS extensions.

Your only real "loss", then, would be having an improper `font-weight` for older, non-IE browsers like Firefox 3.0 and lower, and Opera 9.2x and lower.

So is it really worth JavaScript or PHP browser sniffing to change the `font-weight` for a very limited subset of older browsers?

If the answer is still yes, there are PHP browser sniffers like [this one](http://green-beast.com/experiments/php_browser_sniffer.php).

Comment: And just a note, that PHP sniffer would need new entries for Firefox 3.5 (as well as many other, newer browsers for that matter), and also it makes extensive use of `eregi()` which is now deprecated if you are using PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: OK? Did I say it could not be fixed? The implication was that if you are in the script adding entries you may as well move everything away from `eregi()`. But thanks for nitpicking…

Answer (score 6):

Okay, it is a little late but for people like me who weren't happy to hear the answer above, there is a way to do it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #myDiv
            {
                background-color:blue;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
            }

            @-moz-document url-prefix()
            {
                #myDiv
                {
                    background-color: red;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome - exactly what I was looking for to fix something that differed by 1 pixel vertically between Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CSS Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/).

Answer (score 1):

Conditionals are for IE only, sorry. Maybe some of those functions can help you, they work in gecko browsers only: [Mozilla css extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions)

Comment: thanks to your answer ... yes I know these extensions but I can't override the values for text-shadow and font-weight!!!